# Dynamic form field adding clears the input for all fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I have created a form that you can dynamically add and remove fields to. I am so close to getting it working, but for some reason I can fill in the first fields, add a new field and the first field data remains. Then when I add a second field, fill it in and add another, it will clear all existing data.

I can tell that the `flatpickr` calendar is always on the first field, but then when I add subsequent fields, the `flatpickr` calendar only applies to the last field and won't actually show for any in between. I really need some help as I've spent so long trying to figure it out :(

I believe this is an issue with my JS and how it gets the last element, not how it calls the `flatpickr` library.

Here is all my code in a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/danboy4/w9s9ayep/

Thanks!

Comment: is there any limit to how much fields you need?? after recursively clicking Add button.

Comment: There are no limits, the user should be able to add as many as they want. @IOGAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right with your assumption that the error was located at how it gets the last element. 
You had the following code:

```
var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
$(".after-add-more").after(html);

var lastInput = $(".control-group").closest(".start").prevObject 
var lastInput2 = lastInput[lastInput.length-2].getElementsByClassName("start")[0];
```

This would add the new copied fields directly after the first input box but when getting the element from the array you wanted to use flatpickr on you'd use  `lastInput.length-2`. This index would always be the index of the LAST visible box. The problem was that the box you newly added was not the LAST visible box but actually the second one (because it is directly added after the first input box). Therefore it would overwrite the previous values.

So if you just change `var lastInput2 = lastInput[lastInput.length-2].getElementsByClassName("start")[0];` to `var lastInput2 = lastInput[1].getElementsByClassName("start")[0];` it'll work as it's supposed to be.

Alternatively you could leave the `var lastInput2 = lastInput[lastInput.length-2].getElementsByClassName("start")[0];` as it is and instead change where the new element is placed. To always place it at end you could do something like this `$("#button").before(html);`

Hope I could help you.

Comment: Ahhh you are amazing! The first solution works and now you made me realise that the elements weren't going to the bottom. When I use $("#button").before(html);, the flatpickr stops showing.

Comment: Glad I could help you. Please mark my answer as accepted answer. Will be my first SO answer. :)
Yeah will check what's the problem with the `("#button").before(html);` It worked for me before...

EDIT: Just checked it and for me the flatpickr show up as they should. https://jsfiddle.net/fscpr5ab/

Comment: Marked and upvoted! Thanks for that, I had something else silly which was causing it. Thanks again